# How to expand a Lorentz transformation to first order in $\beta$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

In Special Relativity we can write a proper Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ as (with just boost for simplicity)

$$\Lambda(\vec{\beta})=e^{-\vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot\mathbf{K}}$$

where $K_i$ are the generators of boosts and $\vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})=\hat{\beta}\tanh^{-1}\beta.$

Now suppose I want to expand this to first order in $\beta$ which is reasonable to do. My insintic would be to expand first the exponential to first order in its arguments

$$\Lambda(\vec{\beta})\approx 1 - \vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}$$

Then expand $\vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}$ to first order in $\beta$. I would have

$$\vec{\xi}({\vec\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}=\vec{\xi}\cdot\mathbf{K}(0)+\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\vec{\xi}\cdot\mathbf{K}(0)\vec{\beta}$$

Now with

$$\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\vec{\xi}\cdot\mathbf{K}=\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\hat{\beta}\tanh^{-1}\beta \cdot\mathbf{K}=\dfrac{\hat{\beta}\cdot\mathbf{K}}{1-\beta^2}$$

But the above derivative is computed on $\beta = 0$ so $\hat{\beta}$ isn't even defined.

This is obviously wrong and I also think it is not even mathematicaly legal to just blindely first expand the exponential and then the argument.

The issue is that the parameter of the exponential is $\xi$ instead of $\beta$ directly.

What is the correct way to perform this expansion?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the exponential that way as long as you keep track of the quantities you're ignoring. For instance the first expansion you write is more correctly:
$$\Lambda(\vec{\beta})\approx 1 - \vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}+o\left(\vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}\right)$$
You're interested in the expansion to first order in $\beta$ and you don't know if the quantity in the little-o is what order. You should therefore first expand the argument of the exponential. Using summation convention,
$$\vec{\xi}(\vec{\beta})\cdot \mathbf{K}=\xi_j(\vec{\beta})K_j$$
and at the same time
$$\xi_j(\vec{\beta}) = \xi_j(0) + \beta_i\frac{\partial \xi_j(\vec{\beta})}{\partial \beta_i} \lvert_{\beta_i=0}+O(\beta^2)$$
If $\beta = |\vec{\beta}|$, the derivative can be computed as:
$$\frac{\partial\xi_j(\vec{\beta})}{\partial \beta_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_i} \left(\frac{\beta_j}{\beta} \tanh^{-1}(\beta) \right)$$
In particular, you also need to differentiate the unit vector. I think you can take it from here. (Notice that you may need to interpret setting $\beta=0$ as a limit)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Following it I arrived at $$\dfrac{\partial \xi_j}{\partial \beta_i}\bigg|_{\beta=0}=\lim_{\beta\to 0}\dfrac{\beta_j}{\beta}\dfrac{1}{1-\beta^2}\dfrac{\beta_i}{\beta}.$$ Now to compute this I thought on using spherical coordinates. We know that $\beta_i = \beta f_i(\theta,\phi)$ where $f_1(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $f_2(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $f_3(\theta,\phi)=\cos\theta$. This allows to take $\beta \to 0$ but the reuslt ends up as $f_i(\theta,\phi)f_j(\theta,\phi)$ so it seems that it depends on the direction. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're right, that limit is path-dependent. However I believe that's not the only part of the derivative?

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way which seems more direct. We can simply use the series for $\tanh^{-1}$ as

$$\tanh^{-1}\beta=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\beta^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

It is then clear that to first order in $\beta$

$$\tanh^{-1}\beta\approx \beta.$$

Expanding the exponential we then have

$$\exp{-\hat{\beta}\cdot \mathbf{K}\tanh^{-1}\beta}\approx1-\hat\beta\cdot \mathbf{K}\tanh^{-1}\beta\approx 1 -\vec{\beta}\cdot \mathbf{K}.$$